# Content Security Policy error when using react-stripe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments, content-security-policy

I'm currently working on a react application that integrates Stripe payments using the `@stripe/react-stripe-js` (version "^1.9.0") and `@stripe/stripe-js` (version "^1.32.0") npm packages. The payments are coming through correctly however on two occasions this month (week ending 3 November 2023) and since 21 November 2023, I note we've received browser devtools errors reported:

```
The Content-Security-Policy directive 'media-src' contains the keyword 'none' alongside with other source expressions. The keyword 'none' must be the only source expression in the directive value, otherwise it is ignored.
```

[image]

I have tried a number of different things from research

- updating the npm packages
- checked routing
- changed the `meta` declaration in our entry point to something like this
- Checked the stripe changelog (could potentially have something to do with PaymentIntent?)

```
<meta http-equiv="content-security-policy"
        content="default-src 'none'; script-src 'self';
        connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self';
        style-src 'self'" />
```

Nothing has worked unless I remove `<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script` from the entry point, which removes stripe entirely from the application.

Can anyone recommend any other possibilities please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you still get the same errors when you add all the required directives for Stripe.js that Stripe has listed here? https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#content-security-policy

Comment: @karbi Thank you so much. yes I have attempted added this tag to my index.html entry point                 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="connect-src 'self' https://checkout.stripe.com; frame-src 'self' https://checkout.stripe.com; script-src 'self' https://checkout.stripe.com; img-src 'self' https://*.stripe.com;">
It stops my other polyfills, scripts unfortunately. Have I got it right?

Answer (score 0):

As the error messages mention sources and directives that are not present in the meta policy you have presented, your site is likely serving multiple policies. Check your response headers. Then locate how the response header policy is being set to adjust your policies and remove redundant ones.